# All possible rows without duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have 2 columns corresponding to moods from a music related database - mood, mood2

I want to return all possible rows without duplicates. Having come across a similar answer on this site I've adapted a query as follows, but am still not getting any viewable results.

```
$resultMOODinner = mysql_query

("SELECT (var) FROM (
     SELECT Mood AS var FROM Music
     UNION
     SELECT Mood2 AS var FROM Music
                   )
AS Temp ");

while ($rowMOOD2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultMOODinner, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
$Mood = $rowMOOD2["Temp"];
echo "$Mood";
  }
```

Comment: your not saying which table to select your data from and your syntax seems wrong

Answer (score 0):

As per comment elsewhere, the **simplest** solution is to use SELECT DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT var 
FROM (
      SELECT Mood AS var FROM Music 
      UNION SELECT Mood2 AS var FROM Music
) as temp
```

However this has to trawl the database twice - however the whole point of a database is that it manages lots of data - you should rarely ever look at all your data at once - indeed you should actively seek other solutions. But disregarding this for now, a much more **efficient** solution is to only read the data once:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF (mult.val='A', mood, mood2)
FROM music,
(SELECT 'A' UNION SELECT 'B') mult
```

BTW your PHP code is selecting an attribute which is not in your query - the Temp alias is applied to the sub-query).

However from the information you've provided the only possible conclusion one can draw is that your database is not normalized - hence the **correct** solution is to normalise your database.

Comment: I got it working in the end using the initial code. Thanks for pointing out the unnecessary use of the temp attribute, which I corrected to var. I managed to get an output but had to insert WHERE clauses for every line of the query for it to work properly, which I'm not 100% comfortable with:

SELECT DISTINCT var FROM (
    SELECT Mood AS var, FixedID as FixedID FROM Music Where AlbumID = '".$VAR8."' AND Album = '".$VARAlbum2."'
    UNION
    SELECT Mood2 AS var, FixedID as FixedID FROM Music Where AlbumID = '".$VAR8."' AND Album = '".$VARAlbum2."'
) AS var ");

Comment: Sorry about the ugly formatting of the reply post. I'm still getting used to this forum.

Answer (score -1):

Use DISTINCT:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Mood AS var FROM Music
 SELECT DISTINCT Mood2 AS var FROM Music
```

Comment: No - the DISTINCT should be on the outer query: SELECT DISTINCT `var` FROM (SELECT Mood AS var FROM Music
     UNION
     SELECT Mood2 AS var FROM Music) as temp - but it would be much more effectienct to transpose the data from a single pass on the table.